# How can I improve image quality in the pdf?

Tags: swift, image, pdf

Working on a pdf photo report app, and struggling with the low image quality in the pdfs that are generated.

```
func drawImage(index: Int, rectPos: Int) {
    let image = getImage(index)
    let xPosition = CGFloat(rectArray[rectPos][0])
    let yPosition = CGFloat(rectArray[rectPos][1])
    image.drawInRectAspectFill(CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, 325, 244))
}

func getImage(index: Int) -> UIImage {
    var thumbnail = UIImage()
    if self.photoAsset.count != 0 {
        let initialRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        initialRequestOptions.resizeMode = .Exact
        initialRequestOptions.deliveryMode = .HighQualityFormat
        initialRequestOptions.synchronous = true
        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(self.photoAsset[index], targetSize: CGSizeMake(325, 244), contentMode: PHImageContentMode.Default, options: initialRequestOptions, resultHandler: { (result, info) -> Void in
            thumbnail = result!
        })
    }
    return thumbnail
}
```

I then use these functions to grab the image and place it into a position on a page after UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(page, nil)...

I'm using [BSImagePicker](https://github.com/mikaoj/BSImagePicker) pod to get the images.

And finally my photoAsset is just an array of PHAsset photos that is generated after the user selects the images from the pod's CollectionView...

So far I tried all the settings for the initialRequestOptions.deliveryMode... highquality doesn't seem to make images any better.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the target resolution when requesting image sets the minimum resolution of the image you are going to use.

instead of:

```
PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(self.photoAsset[index], targetSize: CGSizeMake(325, 244)...
```

I simply doubled the size of the image and the image that is drawn to the pdf is better quality.

```
PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(self.photoAsset[index], targetSize: CGSizeMake(650, 488)...
```